Given $n$ natural numbers, if each of them is perturbed, what is the expected value of the minimizer?
Suppose you have $n$ natural numbers $a_1 = 0$ and $a_2,...,a_n \in \{0,1,...,2^n\}$, and the corresponding $n$ random variables $r_i \sim N(a_i,\sigma^2)$ for each $i \in [n]$ (where $N(x,\sigma^2)$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $x$ and variance $\sigma^2$).
Question: What kind of upper bounds can we get on the expected value of $a_{i*}$ where $i* = \arg \min_{i = 1,...,n} \{r_i\}$?
For each $r_i$ with $i > 1$, we can upper bound the probability that it is the "winner" by the probability that it beats $r_1$. This can be done through the fact that $(r_i - r_1) \sim N(a_i - a_1, 2\sigma^2) = N(a_i, 2\sigma^2)$. Intuitively, if $a_2,...,a_n$ are small, then there is a larger chance of one of them being the winner, but since they are small the expected minimum would also be small (by small here I mean $O(1)$ for example). However, if the $a_2,...,a_n$ are large, they will have a significantly smaller probability of winning. I am wondering if there is a proof of the following conjecture:
Conjecture: $E[a_{i*}] = O(1)$, where $i* = \arg \min_{i = 1,...,n} \{r_i\}$

It is unclear to me what you mean by $a_2,\ldots,a_n \in {0,1,\ldots,2^n}$.  If all the $a_i$ can be $0$ then there will be no limit on the expectation of the minimum as $n$ increases, but if $a_2=0$ and $a_i=2^{n-3}$ for $i>2$ then yes there will be and simulation will give you a close estimate.

Apologies, I initially had the incorrect question--updated now!

Are those $a_i$ deterministic constants which are arbitrarily selected from the set ${0, 1, \ldots, 2^n}$? I presume the $R_i$ are independent. And your conjecture is that as $n \to +\infty$, for any arbitrary sequence  $a_i \in {0, 1, \ldots, 2^n}$, $E[a_{i*}]$ is bounded by some constant $M$.

I think the problem statement could be simply: $a_i$ is a non decreasing sequence with $a_0=0$ (the restriction to different integer values in $[0,2^n]$ seems irrelevant and confusing).

The conjecture does not hold in general. Consider $a_1 = a_2 = \dots = a_n = c_n$ where $P(r_0 \geq c_n) = n^{-1}$. Note that $c_n \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Then
$$ P(\min_{1\leq i \leq n} r_i \geq 0) = (1-P(r_1 < 0))^n = (1-n^{-1})^n \leq e^{-1} $$
while $P(r_0\leq 0) = 1/2$. This means $P(\min_{1\leq i \leq n} r_i \leq r_0) \geq \frac{1-e^{-1}}2$, hence $a_{i*} = c_n$ with positive probability, hence $E[a_{i*}] \geq \frac{1-e^{-1}}2 c_n$ which is not $O(1)$.
If you impose that the $a_i$ are all distinct and integer-valued, then the conjecture holds. Indeed, using the bound $\int_x^\infty e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \mathrm d t \leq x^{-1} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$,
$$ P(r_i \leq r_0) = P(\sigma^{-1} r_0 \geq \sigma^{-1} a_i) \leq \sigma \frac{e^{-\frac{a_i^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{a_i} . $$
Then
$$ E[a_{i*}] \leq \sum_i a_i P(r_i \leq r_0) \leq \sigma \sum_i e^{-\frac{a_i^2}{2\sigma^2}} \leq \sigma \sum_i e^{-\frac{i^2}{2\sigma^2}} < \infty . $$
